Mac Designed for iPad "Failed to look up symbolic reference" ActivityKit
I'm trying to run my iOS app on Mac via the "Designed for iPad" destination. It crashes on launch with this:
Failed to look up symbolic reference at 0x1006ac9bd - offset 162835 - symbol symbolic _____y_____GSg 11ActivityKit0A0C 19MyAppPlayerAttributesV in /private/var/folders/4d/wbdrh95d1pz_f5y659dt22gr0000gn/X/6723F443-F2B3-5BE2-99A0-82DA9EF5CB24/d/Wrapper/MyApp.app/MyApphere

This is because ActivityKit isn't available on Mac. However, even if I try to selectively exclude importing ActivityKit I still get the same crash.
//#if os(iOS) || os(watchOS)
#if canImport(ActivityKit)
import ActivityKit
#endif

Also, every part of the code that references ActivityKit is wrapped in a conditional check e.g.:
#if canImport(ActivityKit)

    func startLiveActivity() {
        guard ActivityAuthorizationInfo().areActivitiesEnabled else { return }
        
        let attributes = AudioPlayerAttributes(audioTitle: memoTitle, startDate: Date())
        let initialContentState = AudioPlayerAttributes.ContentState(isPlaying: isPlaying, currentTime: currentTime, duration: duration)
        
        let content = ActivityContent(state: initialContentState, staleDate: nil)
        
        do {
            activity = try Activity.request(attributes: attributes, content: content, pushType: nil)
            print("*** audioPlayer Live Activity started")
        } catch (let error) {
            print("*** Error starting Live Activity: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }
    
    func updateLiveActivity() {
        guard let activity = activity else { return }

        let updatedContentState = AudioPlayerAttributes.ContentState(isPlaying: isPlaying, currentTime: currentTime, duration: duration)
        let content = ActivityContent(state: updatedContentState, staleDate: nil)
        
        Task.detached(priority: .background) {
            await activity.update(content)
        }
    }
    
    func endLiveActivity() {
        guard let activity = activity else { return }

        // Optionally provide final content
        let finalContentState = AudioPlayerAttributes.ContentState(isPlaying: isPlaying, currentTime: currentTime, duration: duration)
        let content = ActivityContent(state: finalContentState, staleDate: nil)

        Task.detached(priority: .background) {
            await activity.end(content, dismissalPolicy: .immediate)
            print("*** audioPlayer Live Activity ended")
        }
    }
    
#else
func startLiveActivity() { }
func updateLiveActivity() { }
func endLiveActivity() { }
#endif

It's like it's running the iPad version of the app, so it doesn't think it's running on a Mac, but it is, so it can't access ActivityKit.
There must be a work-around? Otherwise any app with a widget wouldn't be available on Mac.
Any help appreciated!

You need to provide more information. You have handled the conditional import of activity kit but how does the rest of your code deal with the unavailability of this framework?  If your code makes unguarded access to activity kit symbols you won't get a compiler warning (because the availability of the framework is determined at runtime) but it will fail at runtime

Refer to the documentation on excluding specific code or even entire files depending on platform https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/configuring-a-multiplatform-app-target#Resolve-build-issues-by-adding-conditional-statements

Thanks @Paulw11 I've added more info. Everywhere that ActivityKit is references I've wrapped in a check. Do you think a condition check like that should work? I also tried changing the condition to check for platform, but I think the "Mac Designed for iPad" thinks it's an iPad when it's actually running on Mac, so those checks didn't work.
